# Joi validating list of objects where all must contain optional key if it is in one object

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, joi

I have a list of objects with the following required keys:

> Date, Time, Price

I want to add an optional key "order" and if one of these objects contains that optional key, they all must. How would I go about validating that with joi?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a schema dynamically depending on the array that is going to be validated. If the array has some objects that have `order` property then schema should require this property from every object in the array, otherwise, schema should treat this property as optional:

```js
const schemaFactory = input =>
  Joi.array().items(
    Joi.object().keys({
      Date: Joi.required(),
      Time: Joi.required(),
      Price: Joi.required(),
      order: input.some(item => item.hasOwnProperty('order'))
        ? Joi.required()
        : Joi.optional()
    })
  )

const input = [
  { Date: 1, Time: 2, Price: 3 },
  { Date: 1, Time: 2, Price: 3, order: true },
]

const schema = schemaFactory(input)
const result = schema.validate(input)

if (result.error) {
  console.log(result.error)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/joi-browser@13.4.0/dist/joi-browser.min.js"></script>
```